# Modify objects.mk makefile that was autogenerated by Eclipse / Nsight

Tags: eclipse, makefile, nsight

I am attempting to compile some code dependent on cufft. When I try to compile it I get the following errors:

undefined reference to `cufftPlan2d'
undefined reference to`cufftDestroy'

Looking at the generated files from the sample cuda code I noticed the objects.mk file is different from my project. The working sample objects.mk has the following line:

LIBS := -lcufft

While my objects.mk has:

LIBS :=

How do I change the settings for the auto generation of the makefile to include this library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to add the library under Project Properties -> Build -> NVCC Linker -> Libraries

[image]